# How to not select links from paragraph using regex

Tags: regex

I try to write a regex code to select words from paragraph but not from links, even if the paragraph contains links.
I've tried this regex code: `<p.*?>(.*?)test(.*?)<\/p>`,
for the: `<p>this <a href="">is a just a test</a>text</p>`

But my code selects also what is in `<a....../a>`.
Is it possible to select words only from `<p>` and not from `<a>`. If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

A relatively simple, but not foolproof, way to do it is to use a negative lookahead to prevent a match if `"</a>"` comes before `"<a "` ahead in the string.

```js
(?!(?:(?!<a\s).)*</a>)
```

Include it immediately before the pattern you want to match, for example, `\bte[sx]t\b`, which by itself would normally match both `"test"` and `"text"`.

```js
const s = '<p>this <a href="">is a just a test</a>text</p>';

console.log(
  s.match(/(?!(?:(?!<a\s).)*<\/a>)\bte[sx]t\b/g)
);
```